# Authorization token passed by user Invalid. Azure Cache

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to create a cache but none of the the IDs or Access keys is working on the to enable the azure cache.  I've gone through the following tutorials:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618003.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic3#_Toc310505080

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618003.aspx

And about 1/2 a dozen different how to create a cache in azure pages and I'm still getting.

Authorization token passed by user Invalid.

I've got a website and cloud service with linked storage and nowhere can I find a url "yourcachename.cache.windows.net" or an Authentication Token in the manage Azure portal.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears the chache settings have been moved to the Cloud Service's role properties in VS. (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/#getting-started-cache-role-instance) I don't see it in the new management portal like it use to be.

Comment: That's one of the dozen different pages I've referenced today.  I feel like I've running in circles on this documentation.

Comment: Your best bet would be to download the Windows Azure Training kit for the sdk version you are using.  There is a hands on lab that should walk you through it.  Here is the link for the latest: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was getting confused between versions of Azure.  I'm not sure what version this started in but I was working in 1.8 and I did not need an access key.  Once I added the below sections to the web.config everything worked.

```
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="{your cache worker role}" />
      <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
  <cacheDiagnostics>
```

And then in order to get Sessions to work I needed to add this:

```
   <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to the old portal via the link on the new portal, click on shared caching, service bus and access control. Create/Select a namespace and the auth token would be displayed on the right hand side bar.